# How to increment dates of specific (dynamic) columns by one year?

Tags: r, loops, date, lapply, na

I keep running into a "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" error.

- I have multiple dataframes (close to 100) with several different *'Date'* columns, including some called *'Period'*... these are formatted slightly differently
- The goal is to quickly iterate over the dataframes, identify any *'Period'* or *'Date'* columns and increase the date value by 1 year.
- Some of the values in *'Period'* or *'Date'* columns may be blank/missing
- This needs to be dynamic in the event another *'Date'* column is added to one of the dataframes in the future

Here a simplified version of the problem I'm working on:

```
grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Period =c('','','201901','201901','201902','201902','201903')
Date_Begin = c('','','2019-01-31','2019-01-13','2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-25')
Date_End = c('','','2019-03-31','2019-04-25','2019-03-01','2019-06-30','2019-07-25')
col4X = c(0,0,"",1.5,1.75,1,NA)
col5Y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df1x =  data.frame(grp,Period,Date_Begin,Date_End,col4X,col5Y)


grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Period =c('','','201904','201904','201907','201907','201908')
Date_Start = c('','','2019-04-30','2019-01-13','2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-25')
Date_End = c('','','2019-07-31','2019-04-25','2019-03-11','2019-06-25','2019-07-20')
Expected_Date = c('','','2019-02-28','2019-06-25','2019-03-06','2019-06-25','2019-07-20')
col4X = c(0,0,"",1.5,1.75,1,NA)
col5Y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df2x =  data.frame(grp,Period,Date_Start,Date_End,Expected_Date,col4X,col5Y)

df_list <- list(df1x, df2x)



rep_fun <- function(df){
  mutate(df, across(matches("Date"), ~ as.Date(.) + 365),
         across(matches("Period"), ~ (as.Date(paste0(., "01"), "%Y%m%d") + 365) %>% format("%Y%m")))
}

lapply(df_list, function(x) rep_fun(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to deal with dates in weird formats is to convert them to dates with `as.Date`, do whatever operation you need to do, then convert it back to the original format using `format`. You can build a base R function with this principle, but my answer uses `dplyr`.

```
rep_fun <- function(df){
  mutate(df, across(matches("Date"), ~ as.Date(.) + 365),
         across(matches("Period"), ~ (as.Date(paste0(., "01"), "%Y%m%d") + 365) %>% format("%Y%m")))
}
```

We are mutating every column that has `"Date"` in the name, turning into date, and adding 365 days. Then we mutate the `"Period"` columns, adding a day `"01"`, turning it into date (specifying the format `"%Y%m%d"`), adding 365 days, and formatting it back to the old format.

You could also use the lubridate package and change `+ 365` to `+ years(1)`, which increases the year by one, regardless of how many days go by.

There were some weird dates in your example, like `'2019-02-31'`, which doesn't exist. Was that intended? Does the code needs to handle that? Because my does not. I changed those days to dates that exist to run the example.

**Result:**

```
> lapply(df_list, function(x) rep_fun(x))
[[1]]
  grp Period Date_Begin   Date_End col4X col5Y
1   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     0     2
2   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     0     2
3   A 202001 2020-01-31 2020-03-30           2
4   A 202001 2020-01-13 2020-04-24   1.5     2
5   A 202002 2020-02-01 2020-02-29  1.75     2
6   A 202002 2020-02-01 2020-06-29     1     2
7   A 202003 2020-03-24 2020-07-24  <NA>     2

[[2]]
  grp Period Date_Start   Date_End Expected_Date col4X col5Y
1   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>     0     2
2   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>     0     2
3   A 202004 2020-04-29 2020-07-30    2020-02-28           2
4   A 202004 2020-01-13 2020-04-24    2020-06-24   1.5     2
5   A 202007 2020-02-01 2020-03-10    2020-03-05  1.75     2
6   A 202007 2020-02-01 2020-06-24    2020-06-24     1     2
7   A 202008 2020-03-24 2020-07-19    2020-07-19  <NA>     2
```

**Altered dummy data (without the impossible dates):**

```
grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Period =c('','','201901','201901','201902','201902','201903')
Date_Begin = c('','','2019-01-31','2019-01-13','2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-25')
Date_End = c('','','2019-03-31','2019-04-25','2019-03-01','2019-06-30','2019-07-25')
col4X = c(0,0,"",1.5,1.75,1,NA)
col5Y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df1x =  data.frame(grp,Period,Date_Begin,Date_End,col4X,col5Y)


grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Period =c('','','201904','201904','201907','201907','201908')
Date_Start = c('','','2019-04-30','2019-01-13','2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-25')
Date_End = c('','','2019-07-31','2019-04-25','2019-03-11','2019-06-25','2019-07-20')
Expected_Date = c('','','2019-02-28','2019-06-25','2019-03-06','2019-06-25','2019-07-20')
col4X = c(0,0,"",1.5,1.75,1,NA)
col5Y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df2x =  data.frame(grp,Period,Date_Start,Date_End,Expected_Date,col4X,col5Y)

df_list <- list(df1x, df2x)
```

**Session info:**

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)

locale:
LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8
LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8                     
LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8

other attached packages:
dplyr_1.0.9
```

Comment: Just curious why do you prefer `as.Date` vs `lubridate::as_date`?

Comment: Apologies for the weird dates, those weren't intended and aren't in the actual dataset I'm working on. Is there a reason the function specifies "dfx2"? In the actual problem, I have 100+ dataframes to update, so specifying a dataframe isn't ideal.

Comment: The code throws a "x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" error

Comment: @Dgamelin no! That was a typo, it was supposed to be `df`, the argument of the function. I edited the answer. I was getting the same errors because of the impossible dates, once i changed those, the function worked. I added the altered dummy data to the answer also.

Comment: @Jamie no specific reason, maybe the lubridate version is better, but in this case i guess the base version does the trick.

Comment: Weird, I use your updated data without the impossible dates and I still get the "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(matches("Date"), ~as.Date(.) + 365)`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro I updated the original question to use your corrected sample data (no impossible dates) and your function in case this makes it easier.

Comment: Running exactly the code chunk in your new edit yields the correct result in my machine. Maybe the issue is with R version, packages versions, or locale variables. I added my session info and you can check if there is any divergence with yours. You could also try the function with your actual dataset to check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function `incr1` that adds exactly one year using `seq.Date` and wrap it in `rep_fun`. This will automatically take account for leap years and daylight saving time stuff. We make a case handling for format of the *Period* or *Date* columns.

Invalid dates in your data such as `2019-04-31` will get deleted (throws a `warning`), fix this first. Also columns with unexpected will be returned `NA` with a `warning`. I think that's cool because correct handling of dates might be important in life.

```
rep_fun <- \(df) {
  incr1 <- \(x) {
    x[x %in% ''] <- NA
    na <- is.na(x)
    lna <- length(na[na])
    nna <- which(!na)
    if (all(grepl('^\\d{6}$', na.omit(x)))) {
      x[nna] <- paste0(x[nna], '01')
      x <- as.Date(x, '%Y%m%d')
      for (i in nna) {
        x[i] <- seq.Date(x[i], by='year', length.out=2)[[2]]
      }
      out <- format(x, '%Y%m')
    }
    else if (all(grepl('^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$', na.omit(x)))) {
      x <- as.Date(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
      nna <- which(!is.na(x))
      for (i in nna) {
        x[i] <- seq.Date(x[i], by='year', length.out=2)[[2]]
      }
      out <- x
    } else {
      warning('Unexpected column format, NAs created.')
      out <- NA_character_
    }
    if (length(is.na(out)) > lna) warning('Invalid dates detected, NAs created.')
    out
  }
  dc <- grep('Date|Period', names(df))  ## date columns
  df[dc] <- lapply(df[dc], incr1)
  df
}
```

### Gives

```
lapply(df_list, rep_fun)
# [[1]]
#   grp Period Date_Begin   Date_End col4X col5Y
# 1   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     0     2
# 2   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     0     2
# 3   A 202001 2020-01-31 2020-03-31           2
# 4   A 202001 2020-01-13 2020-04-25   1.5     2
# 5   A 202002 2020-02-01 2020-03-01  1.75     2
# 6   A 202002 2020-02-01 2020-06-30     1     2
# 7   A 202003 2020-03-25 2020-07-25  <NA>     2
# 
# [[2]]
#   grp Period Date_Start   Date_End Expected_Date col4X col5Y
# 1   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>     0     2
# 2   A   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          <NA>     0     2
# 3   A 202004       <NA> 2020-07-31          <NA>           2
# 4   A 202004 2020-01-13 2020-04-25    2020-06-25   1.5     2
# 5   A 202007 2020-02-01 2020-03-11    2020-03-06  1.75     2
# 6   A 202007 2020-02-01 2020-06-25    2020-06-25     1     2
# 7   A 202008 2020-03-25 2020-07-20    2020-07-20  <NA>     2

# Warning messages:
# 1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 5: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 6: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
# 7: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Invalid dates detected, NAs created.
```

**Note** R > 4.2 was used.

---

*Data:*

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(grp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), Period = c("", "", "201901", "201901", "201902", "201902", 
"201903"), Date_Begin = c("", "", "2019-01-31", "2019-01-13", 
"2019-02-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-25"), Date_End = c("", "", 
"2019-03-31", "2019-04-25", "2019-03-01", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-25"
), col4X = c("0", "0", "", "1.5", "1.75", "1", NA), col5Y = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
)), structure(list(grp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    Period = c("", "", "201904", "201904", "201907", "201907", 
    "201908"), Date_Start = c("", "", "2019-04-31", "2019-01-13", 
    "2019-02-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-25"), Date_End = c("", 
    "", "2019-07-31", "2019-04-25", "2019-03-11", "2019-06-25", 
    "2019-07-20"), Expected_Date = c("", "", "2019-02-31", "2019-06-25", 
    "2019-03-06", "2019-06-25", "2019-07-20"), col4X = c("0", 
    "0", "", "1.5", "1.75", "1", NA), col5Y = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L)))
```